# Issues with Python 3 Multiprocessing Pool Port Scanner

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, port-scanning

The code is:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import socket

target = 'hackthissite.org'
list1 = []
def f(port):
    s = socket.socket()
    try:
        con = s.connect((target,port)
        print("Success:",port)
        s.close()
    except:
        print("Didn't work:",port)
        s.close()
        pass

#This function creates a list to iterate through for the map function
def port_list():
        port_range = int(input("How many ports would you like to scan?"))
        for x in range(1, port_range + 1):
             list1.append(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     port_list()
     with Pool(2) as p:
            p.map(f,list1)
            print("Done")
```

No matter how many ports or workers in the pool it gives me:
Debug adapter process has terminated unexpectedly

But if I pass it the ports I want manually with p.map(f,(80,)) it works 
100% fine. For some reason, passing it a relatively big list like 
range(1,80) and using any number of processes kills it? This is in VS Code by the way.

Comment: "Debug adapter process has terminated unexpectedly" sounds like VS Code's debug feature is having trouble with the subprocesses. Have you tried if things work if you run without VS Code's debugger?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add a timeout.

```
socket.setdefaulttimeout(.5)
```

and instead of swallowing all exceptions, use

```
except socket.timeout:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import socket

target = 'hackthissite.org'
list1 = []
def f(port):
    s = socket.socket()
    s.settimeout(.25)
    try:
        con = s.connect((target,port))
        print("Success:" + str(port))
        s.close()
    except:
        print("Didn't work:" + str(port))
        s.close()
        pass

#This function creates a list to iterate through for the map function
def port_list1():
        port_range = input("How many ports would you like to scan?").split(' ')
        for val in port_range:
             list1.append(int(val))

        print(list1)

def port_list2():
        port_range = input("enter the port range you want to scan ex 1-10 ").split('-')
        for i in range(int(port_range[0]), int(port_range[1]) + 1):
             list1.append(int(i))

        print(list1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     port_list2()
     with Pool(2) as p:
            print(p.map(f,list1))
            print("Done")
```

first function lets you manually enter ports separated with spaces, so try 22 and 80, they should be successful. I did this using `22 80 8080` for input when ran with `port_list1()` and then did `1-1000` for input with `port_list2()`